# Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create-room'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I am stuck with this error and cant' seem to figure out the solution. I was following a YouTube course on channel  called "Traversy Media"  and it's title is "Python Django 7 hour course" and this part is around 01:39 min into the video "CRUD" section.

this is the home.html file

```
{% extends 'main.html'%} {% block content %}

<h1>Home PAGE</h1>

<div>
  <a href="{% url 'create-room' %}">Create room </a>
  <div>
    {% for room in rooms %}
    <div>
      <span>@{{room.host.username}}</span>
      <h4>
        {{room.id}} -- <a href="{% url 'room' room.id %}">{{room.name}}</a>
      </h4>
      <small>{{room.topic.name}}</small>
      <hr />
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

There is a 'create room' link in the home page and this link redirects to a room-form.html file below which is a template for creating and updating a room.

```
{% extends 'main.html' %} {% block content %}
<div>
  <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

here is the urls.py file

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('room/<str:pk>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('create-room/', views.createRoom, name='create-room'),

]
```

here is the views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Room

# Create your views here.=


def home(request):
    rooms = Room.objects.all()
    context = {'rooms': rooms}
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)


def room(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'room': room}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)


def createRoom(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'base/room_form.html', context)
```

and here is the models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # participants =
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:40]
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't even know why this error is happening.

Comment: I think it should be `<int:pk>/` so `path('room/<int:pk>/', views.room, name='room')` see if it works.

Comment: Yeah <int:pk>/ solved it thanks bro.  Oh this tiny mistake almost made me quit the framework. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<str:pk>/` to `<int:pk>/` so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    #...
    path('room/<int:pk>/', views.room, name='room')
    #...
]
```